# Cant enter admin page with SSL

Tags: admin, ssl, https

I want to force all user to access https (SSL) entire website.
I tried to set it at options-general.php page,I try to install a plug-in.
They are all success.But I can't enter or access all wp-admin page either.
The website will redirect to myaccount page when force to SSL is on.

how can i access admin page with ssl? what did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the exact problem here is but you could try adding the following line in `wp-config.php` file

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Let me know how this works out.

Comment: I tried this too, but still the same, will redirect to my account page. If I disable **define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);**  , I can access backstage again

Comment: can i have your website URL?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your site root:

```
#Force SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Don't add it inside the WP rules (`# BEGIN WordPress`, `# END WordPress`).

This will redirect all requests to HTTPS. Also change your URLs in the WP-Backend (options-general.php).

If the plugin you've installed causes the error and you can't deactivate it via WP-Backend just rename or delete the folder via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Wordpress Codex for Administration Over SSL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL)

> "The website will redirect to myaccount page when **force to SSL is on**."

If you are referring to 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN' in wpconfig then the problem might be because you are using a reverse proxy or CDN like Cloudflare.  The Codex solution:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
}
```